# Good rendering in 360 and the stereoscopic settings

Tags: rendering

I render stereoscopic images in 360 for VR
And I have 2 questions:

1. When you look through the binoculars of the VR you see in the upper part the seam where the images connect. How can I not see this seam? What should be changed in the settings?
2. In the settings of stereoscopic, what are the optimal data for an image to come out three-dimensional and as realistic as possible? That the distant objects will look three-dimensional and beautiful and the close ones will not stand out too much?

Comment: The default main settings in the camera are usually close to human vision, like _Mode_: _Off-Axis_, _Convergence Plane_: 1.95 m and _Interocular Distance_ 0.065 m (6.5 cm, but you could measure your pupil distance for a more accurate value) to give good results - if you're scene is modeled with life-size dimensions. I don't know which VR system you use (I only have PSVR), so I have no idea what to do about the seams because I had no problems yet. There is a option for _Spherical Stereo_ and when you activate it there is another option _Use Pole Merge_, but I do not know how they work.